# I would like to sync on iCloud a folder that is in users>username>library>containers, is this possible?

Tags: icloud

I have a game from the App Store that keeps its save files in the Users > YourUserName > Library > Containers > Name of Application.

I would like to automatically have those files saved in iCloud, is this possible or would I have to manually make a backup by creating a custom folder in iCloud and copying/pasting those files in there every so often?

Thanks.

Comment: If this is for backup, might be better/easier just to rely on Time Machine backup.

Comment: @Gilby Thanks but I'm looking for an automatic cloud solution.